# New upload settings Scrapy 0.26

Tags: python, scrapy

`Settings.overrides` attribute is deprecated and won't be supported in Scrapy 0.26, use `Settings.set(name, value, priority='cmdline')` instead
  settings.overrides.update(options)

After the release of 0.26 version Scrapy moved to a new kind of transfer settings. How to pass a bunch of settings now? Previously, everything was kept in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the new set function wraps each setting around a `SettingsAttribute` class. The `set` function looks like this:

```
 def set(self, name, value, priority='project'):
    if isinstance(priority, six.string_types):
        priority = SETTINGS_PRIORITIES[priority]
    if name not in self.attributes:
        self.attributes[name] = SettingsAttribute(value, priority)
    else:
        self.attributes[name].set(value, priority)
```

Below it, in the source code, is a function named `setdict`.

```
 def setdict(self, values, priority='project'):
    for name, value in six.iteritems(values):
        self.set(name, value, priority)
```

You could use that function or a for loop to call the `set` function.

[source](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/acbde40fe7e1e2db5859d6a2ec94414f38c0f30a/scrapy/settings/__init__.py#L95)

Comment: Strange how I never noticed function setdict. Thanks very much, it seems to work!